# how to merge two arrays in a single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays in php

```
  Array
     (
       [0]=>30
     )
  Array
     (
       [0]->43
     )
```

i want to merge these arrays in a single array my desired output is

```
  Array
      (
       [0]=>30
       [1]=>43
      )
```

can anyone tell me how to achieve this

```
      function get_minutes($sess_time)
    {
# code...
if (strstr($sess_time, ':'))
{
    $separatedData = split(':', $sess_time);

    $minutesInHours    = $separatedData[0] * 60;
    $minutesInDecimals = $separatedData[1];

    $totalMinutes = $minutesInHours + $minutesInDecimals;
}
else
{
    $totalMinutes = $sess_time * 60;
}
if ($totalMinutes<=60) 
{
    # code...
    return $totalMinutes;
}
else
{
$result=$totalMinutes/60;
$y=explode(".",$result);
$hours=$y[0];
$hours_mins=$hours*60;
$remaining_mins=$totalMinutes-$hours_mins;
$remaining_array=array($remaining_mins);
 print_r($remaining_array);
}

}
```

when i print the remaining array the ourput is two arrays

Comment: If you want to merge arrays, why not use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php) ?

Comment: @roberto06 how to use it because i have only one array which is $remianing_array

Comment: @NareshKumar.P CHECK THE EDITED QUESTION PLEASE

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad Arent you realizing you turned capslock on? Like... what is going on with those Indians?

Comment: `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $remaining_array);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

**array_merge** — Merge one or more arrays

Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

Array

```
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp